# Replace 2 spaces with 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to replace all the values within a column that are:

```
 Boston,  MA             (2 space)
```

with:

```
 Boston, MA              (1 space)
```

I have gotten as far as:

```
select [Location], replace(replace(replace([Location],' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') from [Table]
```

How can I replace the values in the [location] column with the result of the query above?

note: there are other values in the [location] column, eg.

```
Hong Kong
London, UK
```

Comment: `replace(field, 'spacespace', 'space')`?

Comment: Take a look at this article. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/ It explains how to replace multiple spaces with a single space. If you only have 2 spaces then the fine code that M.Ali posted will work great. If however, you find that you have multiple spaces the article I linked shows a great way to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [Location], replace([Location],'  ', ' ') from [Table]
```

to update the column

```
UPDATE [Table]
 SET [Location] = replace([Location],'  ', ' ')
```